# How to open a new chrome tab using selenium webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, tabs, automated-tests

Upon researching, I found out that Control + t doesn't work for the Chrome webdriver. The following are some that I've tried and did not work:

```
    String selectLinkOpeninNewTab = Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL,"t");
    driver.findElement(By.tagName("body")).sendKeys(selectLinkOpeninNewTab);
    driver.get("www.facebook.com");
```

and

```
    WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Gmail"));
    Actions actionOpenLinkInNewTab = new Actions(driver);
    actionOpenLinkInNewTab.moveToElement(element)
                            .keyDown(Keys.COMMAND)
                            .keyDown(Keys.SHIFT)
                            .click(element)
                            .keyUp(Keys.COMMAND)
                            .keyUp(Keys.SHIFT)
                            .perform();

    ArrayList tabs = new ArrayList (driver.getWindowHandles());
    driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(1));
    driver.get("http://www.yahoo.com");
    driver.close();

    driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(0));
    driver.get("http://www.yahoo.com");

    driver.close();
```

and

```
    ArrayList<String> tabs = new ArrayList<String>  (driver.getWindowHandles());
    driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(1)); //switches to new tab
    driver.get("https://www.facebook.com");
}
```

Were any of you able to step around this?

Answer (score 1):

**C#**

Use this code to open new tab & switch between tabs:

Use Waiter.

tabs index starts from 0 for 1st tab.

```
var body = Waiter.Until(ExpectedConditions.PresenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.TagName("body"))).FirstOrDefault();
body.SendKeys(Keys.Control + 't');
var tabs = GlobalDriver.WindowHandles;
GlobalDriver.SwitchTo().Window(tabs[1]);
GlobalDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl("Url");
```

The code is in *C#*

It will be somehow similar in *Java*, just the syntax will be different.

Hope this helps you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Java Robot to send Ctrl+t (or Cmd+t if MAC OS X) and the wait for the new handle to be opened, for example:

```
// Open URL in default tab
driver.get("https://wikipedia.org/");

// If Mac OS X, the key combination is CMD+t, otherwise is CONTROL+t
int vkControl = IS_OS_MAC ? KeyEvent.VK_META : KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL;
Robot robot = new Robot();
robot.keyPress(vkControl);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_T);
robot.keyRelease(vkControl);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_T);

// Wait up to 5 seconds to the second tab to be opened
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.numberOfWindowsToBe(2));

// Switch to new tab
List<String> windowHandles = new ArrayList<>(driver.getWindowHandles());
System.err.println(windowHandles);
driver.switchTo().window(windowHandles.get(1));

// Open other URL in second tab
driver.get("https://google.com/");
```

[Here](https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager-examples/blob/master/src/test/java/io/github/bonigarcia/wdm/test/OpenNewTabChromeTest.java) you have a running example using Chrome as browser.